# The rebase commit order confusion

Tags: git

I get this snapshot of `git rebase`:

[image]

you see the feature commits is in the front of master after rebase.

but however, I test in my repo, (origin/repo master vs local/repo master).

the commit order is local/repo master is in the front after rebase.

the result:

Time sequence of commits:

```
local/repo master 1111

origin/repo master 333
origin/repo master 444
origin/repo master 555
```

after rebase from

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
* a7b57ce (HEAD -> master) 1111   # this commit of local/repo master become the latest. 
* 4255c42 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) 555
* 0eafba2 444
* 4838fca 333
```

this violates the snapshot which display the be rebased branch commits should in front of the one who initiate the rebase.

Comment: Did you `git rebase master` while being checked out on `local` branch, or did you `git rebase local` while being checked out on `master` branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction you rebase in affects the results:

## Rebase foo onto bar:

```
git log --oneline --graph foo bar

* 7b56f8f (HEAD -> bar) 33
| * 4ac5cb6 (foo) 22
|/  
* 0d5ab43 11

git checkout foo
git rebase bar
git log --oneline --graph foo bar

* 35c0b9e (HEAD -> foo) 22
* 7b56f8f (bar) 33
* 0d5ab43 11
```

## Rebase bar onto foo:

```
git log --oneline --graph foo bar

* 7b56f8f (HEAD -> bar) 33
| * 4ac5cb6 (foo) 22
|/  
* 0d5ab43 11

git checkout bar
git rebase foo
git log --oneline --graph foo bar

* affebfd (HEAD -> bar) 33
* 4ac5cb6 (foo) 22
* 0d5ab43 11
```